# How to get more than one thumbnail image back with requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes

Tags: objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications, mpmovieplayer, video-thumbnails

I'm able to play a video using `MPMoviePlayerController`.  The method `requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes` lets me put in an array of multiple times to get a thumbnail, but in `MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification` I can only get back one image from the first time in my times array.  How can I get the other images requested at the other times in my array?

In my `viewDidLoad`:

```
[self.movieController requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:self.timesArray timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification object:self.movieController];
```

Notification:

```
-(void)MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification: (NSNotification*)note
{

NSDictionary * userInfo = [note userInfo];
UIImage *image = (UIImage *)[userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
if(image!=NULL)
    [self.trippingBalls setImage:image];

}
```

Comment: What do you see when you print off the user info `NSDictionary`?

Comment: @lindonfox
I get the thumbnail image data for the one image (the first timely in my array, which has multiple time keys) : 
{
    MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey = "<UIImage: 0x1702836b0> size {720, 1280} orientation 0 scale 1.000000";
    MPMoviePlayerThumbnailTimeKey = "1.4";
}

Comment: [this method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPMoviePlayerController/requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:timeOption:) might be what you need to use. Sorry I have not dealt with this before, but you may need to access them using this method.

Comment: The docs say each request is processed separately -- so the delegate method should be called multiple times, once for each thumbnail. Have you checked for this?

Answer (score 0):

may be it will help you ...

```
-(UIImage *)generateThumbImage : (NSString *)filepath
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

    AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time = [asset duration];
    time.value = 0;
    CGImageRef imageRef = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

    return thumbnail;
}
```

time.value = 1000 //Time in milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this by adding each UIImage I received into an array.

I had added a UIGestureRecognizer on top of my MPMoviePlayerController, so on each tap method, I added the UIImage I received from my Notification to my array.

Tap method:

```
- (void)handleRollTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
float time = [self.movieController currentPlaybackTime];
[self.timesMutableArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:time]];
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

self.timesArrayToPass = [NSArray arrayWithArray:self.timesMutableArray];
[self.movieController requestThumbnailImagesAtTimes:self.timesArrayToPass timeOption:MPMovieTimeOptionExact];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification object:self.movieController];

[self.images addObject:self.image];

NSLog(@"%@", self.images);
}
```

Notification:

```
-(void)MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageRequestDidFinishNotification: (NSNotification*)note
{
   NSDictionary * userInfo = [note userInfo];
self.image = (UIImage *)[userInfo objectForKey:MPMoviePlayerThumbnailImageKey];
    [self.imageView setImage:self.image];
}
```